# How to use javascript libraries on a chromebook?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chromebook

I'm attempting to code on a chromebook. Is there any way to download and use libraries like jQuery on a Chromebook? If anybody could help me, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an external hard or flash drive, you can put the libraries on there, along with the files.

But wait.

Hard drives can cost a lot of money, so another option is to download the libraries, then put the libraries in the same folder as the files, or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use  front-end libraries, like jQuery, without needing to download them. Add this script tag to the head of your html and you will be able to use the jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```